# Bind URL to React components given state(s)

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, url, bind

I’d like to share a link that reflects React components state(especially form’s input element’s states).

I don’t know what is the right method. I think I have to map the  states the component to an url. But I don’t know how :(

Thank you any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach could definitely work. You could for instance serialize your form inputs and put it in the query part of the URL, using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (see methods `set` and `toString`)